# Next.js 13 getting access to react states during form action

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to figure out how can I do something like "isLoading" behaviour known from react in next.js 13.4 with app project type. That what is happening here is not working correctly, I tried in many ways to do it, but didn't find solution. Maybe somebody here would know what to do here.
I was submitting my form with `action={getForm}`where I had code from `getForm()` and `submitForm` together, but I tried something weird, that you can see below but it didn't work too.
So my question here is: how can I do something before invoke that async function that I think, because of it, it doesn't work as I expected.

```
"use client";
import Button from "@/components/button";
import Input from "@/components/input/";
import submitWishes from "@/system/submitWishes";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import LeadText from "@/components/leadText";
import { ImSpinner2 } from "react-icons/im";
export default function Page() {
  const [nameError, setnameError] = useState(false);
  const [wishesError, setwishesError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  async function getForm(e) {
    var isName = false;
    var isWishes = false;
    if (e.get("name").valueOf().length === 0) {
      isName = true;
      setnameError(true);
    }
    if (e.get("wishes").valueOf().length === 0) {
      isWishes = true;
      setwishesError(true);
    }
    if (isName || isWishes) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  async function submitForm(e) {
    if (e.get("upload").valueOf().size !== 0) {
      e.delete("upload");
      for (const f of files) {
        e.append("upload", f);
      }
    }

    const response = await submitWishes(e);

    if (response && response.type == "error") {
      toast.error(response.message, {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "colored",
      });
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
    return true;
  }
  return (
    <form
      action={async (e) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await getForm(e);
        if (res) {
          await submitForm(e);
          setIsLoading(false);
        } else {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      }}
      className={"flex flex-col gap-4 max-w-xl"}
    >
      <ToastContainer />
      <LeadText>blabla</LeadText>
      <Input
        label={"blabla"}
        id={"name"}
        placeholder={"blabla"}
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (e.target.value.length !== 0) {
            setnameError(false);
          }
        }}
        isError={nameError}
        errorMessage={"blabla!"}
        required={true}
      />
      <Input
        label={"blabla"}
        id={"wishes"}
        placeholder={"blabla"}
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (e.target.value.length !== 0) {
            setwishesError(false);
          }
        }}
        type={"textarea"}
        isError={wishesError}
        errorMessage={"blabla"}
        required={true}
      />
      <Input
        label={"blabla"}
        id={"upload"}
        type={"file"}
        files={files}
        setFiles={setFiles}
      />
      <Button disabled={isLoading}>
        {isLoading && <ImSpinner2 className={"animate-spin"} />}
        {isLoading ? "Sending..." : "Send"}
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

## **EDIT**

I did it other way.

I simply created onSubmit instead of action

```
 <form onSubmit={submitForm} className={"flex flex-col gap-4 max-w-xl"}>
```

and inside of it it works fine:

```
async function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    const wishes = e.target.elements.wishes.value;
    const name = e.target.elements.name.value;
    var isName = false;
    var isWishes = false;
    var uploadArray;
    if (files.length === 0) {
      uploadArray = [];
    } else {
      uploadArray = [...files];
    }
    if (name.length === 0) {
      isName = true;
      setnameError(true);
    }
    if (wishes.length === 0) {
      isWishes = true;
      setwishesError(true);
    }
    if (isName || isWishes) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      return false;
    }
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("wishes", wishes);
    data.append("name", name);
    for (const f of uploadArray) {
      data.append("upload", f);
    }
    const response = await submitWishes(data);
    setIsLoading(false)
    router.push("/wishes/success")

  }
```

But still I wonder if there is a way to do it with `action`